# How does a pilot replace their logbook if it has been lost?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging

I got my private pilot license when I was 17 but was unable to continue flying. I am moving into a position to get back in the air, but I no longer have my log book as it was lost between moves. What is the best way to move forward?

Comment: To move forward with what? Why specifically do you want to prove how many hours you have? Do you actually have a pilot's license?

Comment: I assume so - "I got my private pilot license when I was 17"

Comment: @egid Yes, I guess my main point was to clarify if he just wants to restart flying (in which case an 8710 would be fine) or if he's trying to get a specific rating or even job where he needs to prove a certain number of hours cross-country or in type or whatever.

Comment: @Pondlife I just want to restart recreational flying and possibly pursue additional ratings.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best approach is to start a new logbook with totals that carry over from your latest FAA 8710 - in this case, it sounds like you will roll back to the hours from when you earned your private pilot certificate. There are [some other options listed in FAA Order 8900.1, 5-172](http://fsims.faa.gov/PICDetail.aspx?docId=8900.1,Vol.5,Ch1,Sec8), but it's unlikely any of them will work for your situation (except, perhaps for "Receipts for aircraft rentals", if your FBO is still open and still has the records).

You can request a copy of your 8710 from the FAA, which I'm gonna quote here because that's the best way to not screw anything up:

> Airmen who have lost their logbooks or flight records may request copies of their files from the FAA [by sending ***[this form](http://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/media/COMPRQST.pdf)***] to the following:
>
> > FAA Airmen Certification Branch, AFS-760
> >     P.O. Box 25082
> >     Oklahoma City, OK 73125
>
> or
>
> > FAA Aeromedical Certification
> >     P.O. Box 25082
> >     Oklahoma City, OK 73125

Once you receive the copy, the first line in your new logbook should probably summarize all the totals from the 8710 (just like if it was a flight). The remarks would specify "time forward from 8710 dated DD/MM/YYY" or something to that effect.

Best of luck getting your records back!

Comment: What is on an 8710 for a GA pilot?  Reading the description is sounds like it is just your various pilot certificates and ratings.  Would there even be times?

Comment: @JerryKur, an 8710 is an 8710, whether you're GA or not. There are fields for flight experience, only some of which would be required for a PPSEL, for example, but they're definitely there. My 8710 includes 0.5 Helicopter, for example, just 'cause it was in my logbook.

Comment: So how did these entry like your 0.5 of helicopter get to the FAA to put on your records?  I have never sent anything to the FAA unless it is for a rating or medical?

Comment: When you fill out an 8710 for a rating, you can put any time on it that's in your logbook, even if it's in excess of the requirements for that rating. I had 0.5 helicopter in my logbook when I was applying for some advanced rating, so onto the form it went.

Comment: Thanks.  This is a very interesting thread.  I guess I better not lose my log books because it has been several of them since I added my last rating.

Comment: I've just had my Airmen's Records provided from an 8710 request, but they only seem to have my medicals, nothing from my Instrument rating. So the total hours will be that listed on the last medical you got, not from any other training.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote: *"I just want to restart recreational flying and possibly pursue additional ratings"*, you don't technically need your old log book to start flying again if you still have your license.

See the answers on [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/758/what-does-it-take-to-maintain-a-private-pilot-certificate).

You'll need your license, a current medical, and a BFR.
But I don't think you need proof of hours.
   Of course, getting a fully signed off BFR is a lot easier if you have a log book showing recent time, but it is not required.

Comment: Just to point out... he's specifically asking what to do about his logbook, not what he needs to start flying again! Your answer is correct, but maybe is better as a comment on the question?

Comment: And, he doesn't technically need his logbook - but if he *ever* wants a subsequent rating, he does need his total times, and an 8710 that's missing those hours required for Private will probably raise some eyebrows.