# How many flying mileage a pilot should have per year in order to keep his licence valid?

Tags: pilots

Please let me know if possible
Thank you very much

Comment: There is no mileage requirement.  For info on how to maintain a license:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/758/what-does-it-take-to-maintain-a-private-pilot-certificate

Comment: In the US, licenses don't expire, so they are always "valid". Whether you can fly or not (in the US) just depends on currency requirements. If you are flying by yourself, all you might need is a biennial flight review (one flight every 2 years, if you can pass it).

Comment: @Ron Beyer: And the appropriate medical, if required.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Can you tell us which country or regulations you're asking about? The requirements can be different everywhere, e.g. see [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/758/62) for the US, which is quite different from many other countries. A very general answer to your question is that pilots care about *time* flown, not *distance*. If you're new to StackExchange you might find the [tour] is useful.

Comment: Any requirements would be in the form of flying hours, or takeoff & landings, not miles.  (Different airplanes fly at very different speeds.)  For instance, in order to carry passengers, a private pilot must have performed 3 takeoffs & landings in the preceding 90 days.  (14 CFR § 61.57)

Answer (score 3):

There’s no minimum flight time required to retain a pilot certificate, though there are minimum currency standards in order to act as PIC in certain flight situations, or to carry passengers.  See §61.57.

Pilots are also required to complete a Bienneal Flight Review ever 24 calendar months in order to act as PIC aboard an aircraft.  Any successful practical exam for an airman certificate additional category, class or type rating can be substituted for a BFR.

Typ ratings listed on airman certificates expire after 12 calendar months unless the applicant undergoes a recurrent training for the aircraft type and pass a practical exam administered be an aviation examiner or check airman.

Flight instructor certificates do expire after 24 calendar months, unless the CFI:

- Passes a flight instructor refresher course containing both ground and flight training within the preceding 3 calendar months on the expiration date.
- Pass a practice exam for one of the ratings listed on their instructor certificate
- Recommends at least 5 students to take a practical examination in which 80% of whom pass, or
- Work as a chief pilot or check airman for a Part 121 or 135 operation.

See §61.197