# Why do flight schools refuse to tell me the price of a course?

Tags: cost, flight-school

I have searched many flight schools' sites in my area and none mentions prices, I tried to contact by email and later by calling them, but they still won't tell me the price, why is that?
Shouldn't I know they price before I decide to do it?

Especially during a pandemic, they should definitely discourage you to pay meaningless visits to the academy for information on the cost and tell you right away?
Why do flight schools do that?

Comment: The old saying is, "If you have to ask, you can't afford it."

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: @ZeissIkon Why? Many people here do their PPL for fun, they save for it and hence they consider the price they will pay. Especially the price of the aircraft that will be used for flying lessons. That does not mean they can't afford it they absolutely can. After all, they will want to (and even have to to stay current) fly and pay for aircraft rental later.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/627/62)

Comment: There are differences between Part 61 and 141 schools too. From what I have seen, Part 141 schools do put out "average cost per course/rating" due to how the course is structured (X amount of lessons with Y amount of ground/instructor time + Z amount of flight time). Part 61 schools do not have a lot of that course structure so it will be harder to calculate the cost.

Answer (score 45):

Mostly because what takes one individual 50 hours, will take another 75, and someone else 100.

For that reason, most if not all flight schools will only tell you 2 things

- The *minimum* number of hours required to get the certification you're after (PPL, Night Rating, Instrument Rating etc).
- The cost per hour of instruction, and the cost per hour of the various aircraft they use.

While we're on the subject, I should add that you should be wary of putting down a large upfront cost to any school. I have heard too many stories of flight schools going insolvent and students losing their money. Often you will see a discount for "block bookings" - if you can afford it pay just as you go, and if you do decide to upfront a block booking only spend what you could stomach losing.

Comment: Most schools should also be able to provide statistics about hours to PPL:  "Our average student takes between 55 and 70 hours".

Comment: “ I have heard too many stories of flight schools going insolvent” — yup, that was my experience.  Lost a thousand bucks back in the 80s when my school went belly up.  Still don’t have my license.

Comment: This is why you do not find a flight school online. You talk to pilots *at different airfields* and listen to their recommendations. If the school they learned at and give a good review for is still around, there is a good chance it will survive your course as well.